# Getting Events Between Two Dates using MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4060/2

I then created two views as follow:

```
-- stack 1: hire
create view HS1H as
select a.* , min(a.`Effective_Date`)
from `Table1` a
left join `Table1` b on a.`Employee_ID` = b.`Employee_ID`
and a.`Effective_Date` > b.`Effective_Date` 
where a.`Event_Type` = "1_Hire"
group by a.`Employee_ID`;

select * from `hs1h`;

-- stack 1: termination
create view HS1T as
select a.* , min(a.`Effective_Date`)
from `Table1` a
left join `Table1` b on a.`Employee_ID` = b.`Employee_ID`
and a.`Effective_Date` > b.`Effective_Date` 
where a.`Event_Type` = "5_Term"
group by a.`Employee_ID`;

select * from `hs1t`;
```

I want to get the events that happen between first Hire date and first Term date. I used the qry below but returned no results:

```
select a.* 
from `Table1` a
join `hs1h` b on a.`Employee_ID` = b.`Employee_ID`
join `hs1t` c on a.`Employee_ID` = c.`Employee_ID`
where a.`Effective_Date` between b.`Effective_Date` and c.`Effective_Date`;
```

I am not sure what went wrong. I was able run the following two qrys. One returned the events after first hire date, and the other returned the events before first term date. But when I combine them like the one above, it didn't work.

```
select a.* 
from `Table1` a
join `hs1h` b on a.`Employee_ID` = b.`Employee_ID`
join `hs1t` c on a.`Employee_ID` = c.`Employee_ID`
where a.`Effective_Date` > b.`Effective_Date`;

select a.* 
from `Table1` a
join `hs1h` b on a.`Employee_ID` = b.`Employee_ID`
join `hs1t` c on a.`Employee_ID` = c.`Employee_ID`
where a.`Effective_Date` < c.`Effective_Date`;
```

Comment: Can you say what you expect the output to be in this case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cd885/4/0 ?

Comment: The results should be like the last table in the link you sent, but without the hire and term rows. Essentially what I try to retrieve is everything between the Hire and Term events.

Comment: And interesting that your qry ran in the friddle but mine didnt in mysql. They look identical to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE `effective date` 
BETWEEN (select MIN(`effective date`) from `Table1` WHERE `event type` = '1_Hire') 
AND
(select MIN(`effective date`) FROM table1 WHERE `event type` = '5_Term')
```

For the 2nd or 3rd 'hire', things get a little more complicated, but something like this should work...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM TH_Sample_Data a
  JOIN (
  SELECT x.*
     , MIN(y.effective_date) end
     , @i := @i+1 rank
  FROM TH_Sample_Data x
  JOIN TH_Sample_Data y
    ON y.effective_date >= x.effective_date
   AND y.event_type = '5_Term'
     , (SELECT @i:=1) vars
  WHERE x.event_type = '1_Hire'
  GROUP
     BY x.id
    ) b
   ON a.effective_date BETWEEN b.effective_date and b.end
WHERE b.rank = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks Strawberry, this qry returned results, yah! I do have another question, what this qry does is to return the 1st stack, i.e. all the events between the first Hire and first Term. How can I replicate this qry to get the 2nd stack, i.e. events between 2nd Hire and 2nd Term? Thanks!

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, This problem is technically insoluble.

Comment: I can add the primary key to the data using auto-increment integer. I guess, for the 2nd stack, I can add a where clause that make sure the primary key is not in the the first stack.

Comment: Well, when you do, let me know ;-)

Comment: Here is updated the data with index added. I tried with my qry creating the 2nd stack but failed :(

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run it on my end, but getting an error `Unknown column 'x.id' in 'group statement'`

Comment: `index` is a bad name for a column, so I chose a different one

Comment: Sorry I didnt realize that. I reran the qry but the result is the same as first hire stack. I changed the `b.rank=2` to `b.rank=4` then it returned the 2nd hire stack. I dont really know why. See the results here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93fd5/10

Comment: It's the 'first' term... for the 'second' user. If that's not what you want, then more explanation required!

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "first term for the second user". The first qry you provided actually included the 2nd employee `100002` (if you mean user by employee). However, I think the qry returns what I needed after tweaking the `rank=?`. Thanks for your help!!!